# Terraform v0.12.18 for_each in data block is giving error

Tags: foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

My TF version is 0.12.18. I have the below code :

```
data "aws_identitystore_group" "AWSAdministratorAccess" {
  identity_store_id = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.AWSAdministratorAccess.identity_store_ids)[0]
  
  filter {
    attribute_path  = "DisplayName"
    for_each = toset(["SupportAccess","AdminAccess"])
    attribute_value = each.key
  }
}
```

Error I get is:

```
Error: Reference to "each" in context without for_each

  on permissionset_account_assignment.tf line 7, in data "aws_identitystore_group" "AWSAdministratorAccess":
   7:     attribute_value = each.key

The "each" object can be used only in "resource" blocks, and only when the
"for_each" argument is set.
```

I am setting the `for_each` argument. Is this error because of TF v0.12.18?

Comment: You cannot use `for_each` that way. You can however set it at for the entire data source.

Comment: You need to use dynamic blocks instead of `for_each` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.2.x/expressions/dynamic-blocks